# iron-list height not updating when content height is changed

Tags: polymer, custom-element

I have this polymer element in which a list of items are shown. I am populating the list with `iron-list`. Each list item contains a `paper-card`, which hides some other custom elements, when i click a button, the corresponding view will display. Everything upto this part is working fine.

The problem i'm having is, When i show a custom element, or hide the element, the iron-list item height wont update. When i show the element, the element will show behind other views, and when i hide, a white space is appearing with height equal to that of the showed view.

below is the code for the list,

```
<div on-click="clicked" id="feedlist">
<iron-list items="{{feedList}}" as="item">
    <template>
        <card-element field="{{item.id}}" feed-id="{{item.id}}" feed-number="{{item.id}}" feed-title="{{item.title}}" feed-name="{{item.name}}" date="{{item.timeStamp}}"></card-element>
    </template>
 </iron-list>
```

and code for this `card-element` is as given below

```
 <div class="content" id="content">
                <text-input id="note" type="1" note="{{response.note}}" feed-id="[[feedId]]"></text-input>
                <data-viewer id="dataViewer" plugin-data="{{response.data}}" feed-id="[[feedId]]" default-view="gridView" parent="feed"></data-viewer>
                <comment-view id="comment" comments="{{response.comment}}" feed-id="[[feedId]]"></comment-view>
            </div>
```

im hiding and showing, text-input, data-viewer and comment-view or all at once according to button clicks.

Below is the code for toggling the data-viewer,

```
toggleDataView: function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        if (this.isFeed) {
            this.isDataView = false;
            this.isFeed = false;
        }
        this.isDataView = !this.isDataView;
        if (this.isDataView) {
            this.isComment = false;
            this.isNote = false;
            this.$.note.hide();
            this.$.comment.hide();
            this.$.dataViewer.show();
            this._showDragView();
        } else {
            this.$.dataViewer.hide();
            this._hideDragView();
        }
    },
```

Comment: Does this fix itself when you resize the browser window?

Comment: Yes, when i resize the window, it will update

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `updateSizeForItem(item)` https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list#method-updateSizeForItem after you update an item (view, hide, ...)

Comment: Last idea. Call [notifyResize](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list#method-notifyResize) on the iron-list itself.